# Compare 2 list of lists at specific indexes, Python

Tags: python, list, set

I have 2 lists of lists and I want to compare the contents of the sub-lists of each one of the two lists, at specific indexes only, and then save the index of the both list and sub-list when there is a hit, for example compare the:

- The sub list at index 5 of the first list with the sub list at index 0 of the second list, if there are any similarities store indexes of both lists and sub-lists
- The sub list at index 6 of the first list with the sub list at index 3 of the second list,...
- The sub list at index 7 of the first list with the sub list at index 6 of the second list,...

and so on..

I created a for loop that reads all the contents of the first list from index 5 and onward along with their indexes, and a nested for loop that compares them with all the sub-lists of the second list iterating from 0 to 3 to 6 etc. Then by comparing the intersection of both sets at each iteration i save the indexes of all common elements in all sublists.

```
common_a = []
common_b = []

for index_external, item in enumerate(data_db[5:]): #from 5 onwards
   for index_eternal2, item_2 in enumerate(data_ga[::3]): #every three
      both = set(item).intersection(item_2)
      common_a.append([item.index(x) for x in both])
      common_b.append([item_2.index(x) for x in both])
```

The thing is that this checks all elements of the sublists of the first list (from position 5 and onwards) with every 3rd sublist of the second list, BUT I want to check:

- sublist at index 5 in list1 with sublist at index 0 in list2 only
- sublist at index 6 in list1 with sublist at index 3 in list2 only
- sublist at index 7 in list1 with sublist at index 6 in istt2 only
  and so on

I hope what i wrote makes sense ... any suggestions are MORE than welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've employed nested loops to handle a single parameter.  There's a straightforward linear relationship between the two indices.  For instance:

```
for idx1 in range(5, len(data_db)):
    idx2 = 3*(idx1 - 5)
    if data_db[idx1] == data_ga[idx2]:
        # Your code
```

Even better, just `zip` together the elements you need:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(data_db[5:], data_ga[::3]):
    if item1 == item2:
        # Your code
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two for loops/nested loops. One Loop will solve your problem, in which each iteration of the loop will increment list1 with 1 and list2 with 3.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Prune's answer this is how i finally solved it:

```
# -----------

common_a = []
common_b = []
hits_idx1 = []
hits_idx2 = []

for idx1 in range(4, len(data_db)):
    idx2 = 3*(idx1 - 4)   
    if (idx2 < len(data_ga)): #dont get over the 2nd list's length
        both = set(data_db[idx1]).intersection(data_ga[idx2])
        if both: # if it contains elements
            hits_idx1.append(idx1) # save the indexes of the hits external list data_db
            hits_idx2.append(idx2) # save the indexes of the hits external list data_ga
            common_a.append([data_db[idx1].index(x) for x in both]) #the indexes of the internal lists common elements
            common_b.append([data_ga[idx2].index(x) for x in both])
```